# How to separate CSV fields in Excel to be in separate boxes

Tags: excel, csv

For example, I have the following:

```
fname;lname;email
```

...and it's all in one box.

I would like it to be separated in different boxes, like:

```
fname  lname  email
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Got it silly me,

use go to data, form data, delimited with semicolons

:)

figured it a 30 sec after post

Comment: Great you solved it yourself. But in the future please use superuser.com for software related issues :)

Answer (score 3):

How is this related to programming?

Anyway you can just open CSV files in Excel. It supports the CSV format as well. You might only need to specify the separator character. Sometimes it's the semicolon `;`, sometimes it's the comma `,`.

Answer (score 0):

They need to be separated by commas (comma delimited) not semi-colons.

e.g. fname, lname, email

Quotes around text fields wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: No. As BalusC pointed out, when importing a text file into Excel, you can specify what character to use as a delimiter, and there is no need for quotes.

Comment: I've seen several cases of CSV files with semicolons as delimiters. I assume this is popular in cultures where the comma is used as a decimal separator in numeric values. So it's a perfectly valid thing to do, but Anglophones tend to forget.

Comment: Fair enough.  I saw a spec once, (admittedly about 10 years ago now!) that said CSV files should have quotes.

I think specifying other delimiters is an Excel thing, as it kind of takes away from the <i>"Comma Separated"</i> thing...but this question DOES related to Excel, so I'd have to pay that.